# Mark current currency in menu

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I use Wordpress, WooCommerce and WooCommerce Currency Switcher. Instead of using the normal (ugly) dropdown I have created links in the top-bar to change currency. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.woocs_curr_link').click(function () {
       window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + 
       location.pathname + '?currency=' + jQuery(this).data('curr');
    });
 });
```

And here is the link

```
<a href="#" data-curr="EUR" class="woocs_curr_link">EUR</a>
```

This works great but the current currency is not marked out in the meny. It can be fethed with following code:

```
global $WOOCS;
echo $WOOCS->storage->get_val('woocs_current_currency');
```

How can I extend my code to mark out current currency in the top-bar menu?

Thanks!

Comment: use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script , wp_localize_script() to send object for your js code, then use it in the js

Comment: are you using custom link or create wordpress menu for this ?

Comment: Why are you using JS for this to begin with? Why not create the target URL server-side already, and simply output it as the `href` attribute of the link?

Comment: @CBroe I follow this short guide: https://currency-switcher.com/how-to-create-currency-links-without-shortcode/

Comment: @dipmala I have only put these links in a text widget.

Comment: That guide seems to have been written by someone who doesn’t really know too much about what they are doing themselves ... _“But if to place link simply as: `<a href="/?currency=USD">USD</a>` - it will redirect user to the main page - what is not convenient.”_ - yeah well if one refers to the domain root with `/`, that’s what happens ... without the leading slash, this would automatically resolve to the current URL path. (If the current URL contained other query string parameters already, those would get lost with this, granted - but that’s the case with the unnecessary JS solution as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this, direct in the links with the help by fetching the current set currency and then add a class to mark out the right one.

```
global $WOOCS;
$curcur = $WOOCS->storage->get_val('woocs_current_currency');
?>

<ul class="nav-menu nav-curentcy">
  <li <?php if ($curcur == 'EUR') echo " class=\"cur_cur\""; ?>>
    <a href="#" data-curr="EUR" class="woocs_curr_link">EUR</a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if ($curcur == 'USD') echo " class=\"cur_cur\""; ?>>
    <a href="#" data-curr="USD" class="woocs_curr_link">USD</a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if ($curcur == 'SEK') echo " class=\"cur_cur\""; ?>>
    <a href="#" data-curr="SEK" class="woocs_curr_link">SEK</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make menu selected as per given code

## Javascript

```
//document ready
jQuery(function () {
       var currentElement ='<?php echo $_REQUEST['currency']; ?>'; // get current currency
       jQuery( 'a[ data-curr=' + currentElement + ']' ).addClass( 'selected_menu' ); // add css class for current currancy.
     });
```

## Css

```
   .selected_menu{text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
```